# Mail not going as root user - Linux machine

Tags: linux, email-server

[root@linux ~]# sendmail -v user@yahoo.com
/etc/mail/submit.cf: line 545: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': Group writable directory

Can anyone tell why as a root I cant sent a mail , while if I change user to some particular other user it works .

Whats happening can anyone tell me ?

service sendmail restart gives the following :

Shutting down sm-client:                                   [FAILED]
Shutting down sendmail:                                    [FAILED]
Starting sendmail: 451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 91: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/local-host-names': Group writable directory
451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 588: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': Group writable directory
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting sm-client: /etc/mail/submit.cf: line 545: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': Group writable directory
                                                           [FAILED]

Thanks all , found the solution . 
I solved it using

This will set the permissions for every directory sendmail needs to be
non-group writable: 
   sudo chmod go-w / /etc /etc/mail /usr /var /var/spool
/var/spool/mqueue /private

Comment: Besides fixing the warning you have in your question ("group writable directory"), you should post your MTA configuration.

Sometimes root is not allowed to send mails by configuration (and by intent).

Comment: what is MTA configuration ? and we have configured mail as root before in the same machine when we installed the same OS everything same before . I would like to know what the warning means .

Answer (score 1):

To remove (that) warning:

```
chmod g-w /etc/mail/trusted-users
```

However given that wasn't obvious to you from the error message I'd strongly suggest *not* using sendmail, and instead use postfix or one fo the other new, easier to manage MTA's.

Comment: this same permission for directory and files in /etc/mail  exist in another server which works fine .  it works from there .